# update_attribute vs update_attributes Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to update attributes of an object after a certain action.  If I use update_attribute everything saves correctly to the db but I have many things I need updated so it gets very repetitive.

This works fine:

```
order.update_attribute(:order_completed, "true")
order.update_attribute(:stripe_email, params[:stripeEmail])
```

However when I try to use update_attributes my data does not save to the db.

Here is that code:

```
order.update_attributes(order_completed: "true", stripe_email: params[:stripeEmail])
```

Does anyone see where my mistake is?  From everything I've read that should have worked.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`update_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute) will fire validations, whereas [`update_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update) will not. If you know you want to bypass validations the best approach for saving attributes from a Hash is to do this:

```
order.attributes = { order_completed: "true", stripe_email: params[:stripeEmail] }
order.save(validate: false)
```

To see what's failing take a look in `order.errors` or change your call to `update_attributes!` (with the `!`) which will raise an exception showing what validation failed.

## Rails 4 Update

`update_attributes` and `update_attributes!` are aliases for [`update`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update) and [`update!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update-21) in Rails 4+.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  This might be a dumb question but where exactly do I find order.errors, I still want to see what was failing.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: After you did `order.update_attributes` or after doing `order.save` you can then check `order.errors`. Either with a debugger in the controller or by outputting it to the log or whatever suits you.

Comment: @pdobb you're welcome. It's a great answer, so no point adding a new one, better to just add my bit to it :)

Answer (score 0):

update_attributes may also be ruled by the mass assignment constraints. If you're using rails 4 check that you have this covered with something like:

```
params.require(:order).permit(:order_completed, :stripe_email)
```

Comment: This is only the problem if `params[:order]` was the argument to the mass-assignment method. She's building a new hash herself here, so this isn't the issue.